# Adding dictionaries by value by writing + operator

Tags: python, dictionary, operator-overloading, operators

I would like to write the `+` operator for dictionaries.

I know a similar question has been asked before [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031199/adding-dictionaries-in-python), but I would like to write the `+` operator for a dictionary instead.

I know that it is possible to overload an operator in a custom class in Python. However I did not find how to overload an operator in a built-in class (if that is actually possible). Also since the `+` operator is not defined for a dictionary in Python I wonder if that is possible at all?

I think this question has not been asked before on SO since I could not find something like it. Perhaps I just did not find the right terms to search for it. [Another link that might be useful for that question](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html).

Comment: No, but yes, check this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6738987/extension-method-for-python-built-in-types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you want to do is implement add method to dictionaries - You might want to use your own logic, I am here using update method to add. You will have to inherit and overload the add method to make this happen. Here is how to do it.

```
class dicti(dict):
    def __add__(self, obj):
        temp = {}
        temp.update(self)
        temp.update(obj)
        return temp
a = dicti({'a':1,'b':2})
b = dicti({'c':2})
c = a+b
print(a) #outputs -> {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
print(b) #outputs -> {'c':2}
print(c) #outputs -> {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 2}
```